# Symfony validation does not show messages

Tags: validation, symfony, twig

Trying to set up custom messages for validation in Symfony by annotations.

This is what I have...

config.yml

```
validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true }
```

in the entity...

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 5,
 *      max = 6,
 *      minMessage = "Your first name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
 *      maxMessage = "Your first name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters"
 * )
 */
private $nombre;
```

So I try to fire the minMessage by filling the input only with 1 character. It should shows the minMessage but it shows the same message (image below) for all the fields, even for those fields they do not have annotations in the entity.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These validations you define are only server-side validations. The message you show us in your screenshot is a html5 validation message, caused by the browser.

```
<input type="something" required="required" name="...">
```

I don't know spanish so what i'm guessing is the field you rendered is not of the type text and the message tells you that the entered value is not of the correct format. i.E. Text in a number type field. (or maybe in this case the minlength attribute of the field is set)

To disable html5 validation for a form try this

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" .....>
```

or using twig syntax like

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'} }) }}
```

then the html5 validation will no longer prevent the form submit and your backend validation kicks in.